# Symfony2 remove subform label

Tags: forms, symfony

I have created a subform like on Symfony2 documentation page:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/forms.html#form-rendering-template

This code:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('category', new CategoryType());
}
```

It`s simply assign subform Category in form Task. My problem is to see subform name. I want to remove it but I do not now how to do it. I try this, but it doesn't work:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('label' => '');
}
```

Do you have any idea how can I remove this SubForm label?

Comment: Have you tried setting `'label'` to `false`? This should work.

Comment: Yes, I have tried to set label to false but nothing happend. But when you wrote your comment I remember about cache:clear option and it's works! Thx for reply.

Comment: It's always the cache! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have assigned false to the label, and it works. But I am not sure is this good solution. If you have any better idea share it please/

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
{
    // ...

    $builder->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('label' => false);
}
```